# We have a basic login function that logs in, but then it abruptly goes back to the login screen again

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication

So why does it go back to the login screen again? what have we missed here?

user: admin

pass: 1234

so we have a simple login solution (I know pass and user will be visible in the source but this is just a school project to learn php so it doesn't really matter for us in this case.)

this is the relevant code:

```
<head>
   <script>
    var usr ='admin';
    var psw = '1234';
    var loggedIn=false;

    function loggaIn() {
        if ( ($('#idUser').val()== usr) && ( $('#idPsw').val()== psw ) )
        {
            loggedIn=true;
            $('#logdiv').toggle();
            $('#mainOK').toggle();

        }
        else
        {
            alert ("Incorrect username and/or password!")   
        }
    }

    function loggaut() {
        loggedIn=false;
        $('#mainOK').hide();
        $('#loggin').show();

    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="idUser" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="text" id="idPsw" placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <button onclick="loggaIn()" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Log in</button>
</body>
```

Any tips or help towards finding a solution would be much appreciated

Comment: It always matters. School project or not. In fact, since it is a school project it matters more. Unless you've got previous experience in this field, employers will probably ask to see your school portfolio when you graduate. I can't say I'd hire someone who blatantly disregards security concerns.

Comment: That is not PHP, it is actually Javascript. As for it abruptly taking you back, it doesn't seem as if you Javascript is even communicating with the next page correctly / at all. You can not set variables in javascript to be used in PHP, not without additional work anyway. Plus, **don't use Javascript for sessions**

Comment: You have just created a SIN! Use PHP not Javascript...

Comment: POST your username/password to PHP & then decide whether to display inner page or redirect back to login again.

Comment: @Jhecht we are actually Graphic design students, and wont have the nessesery skills to do anything serious in web developing anyway, i understand the consern and i agree but this is the way our proff told us to do it, just to get a quick insight. Security is very important but not for this assignment, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Jhecht changed my mind, its kinda important, if we do this to get an insight we might aswell get a correct one.

Comment: Infallible security!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Such credentials should never be tested in JS code. It is harmful. I totally agree with @void.

POST your username/password to PHP & then decide whether to display inner page or redirect back to login again.

You should learn how to manage login/session using PHP. Here is good resource for you: http://www.sitepoint.com/users-php-sessions-mysql/